# programmatically specify decimal precision of string-formatted float

Tags: python, formatting, floating-point-precision

How do I programmatically specify the decimal precision of a string-formatted float?

Specifically, I'd like to implement the following behavior:

```
>>> print displayNumber(number=math.pi, precision=3)
3.142
```

Answer (score 1):

With the old `%`-formatting style, you can do:

```
>>> def displayNumber(number, precision):
>>>     return "%.*f" % (precision, number)
```

or

```
>>> def displayNumber(number, precision):
>>>     return ("%%.%df" % precision) % number
```

Comment: With the new `{}` formatting style you can do a lot more.

Comment: @vaultah how would you do this in the new style?